# Prove that T is a transitive tournament if and only if $od(u) \neq od(v)$ for all u and v in the vertex set of T

Tags: graph-theory

Proof:

T is a transitive tournament if and only if the degree sequence of T is n-1,n-2,n-3,..., 2,1,0 if $od(u) \neq od(v)$ i.e. all vertices has distinct order and there are only n possible distinct orders which are 0,1,2,...,n-1 which means that one vertex of each order must exist. Hence the degree sequence is n-1,n-2,..., 2,1,0 so that the tournament is transitive.

This is the answer I came too for this problem so I just want know if I am correct or if there is anything I need to revise or correct.

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown is that if the out-degrees are all distinct, then they must be equal to $0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$. 
What you need to show are two things:

1. If a tournament is transitive, then the out-degrees are all distinct;
2. If the out-degrees are all distinct, then the tournament is transitive.

You can use induction on $n$ for both. 
First show that there must be a vertex of out-degree $n-1$; remove this vertex, and show that the induction hypothesis applies to the reduced graph.

Comment: How would I do that exactly because this is a really tough problem.

Comment: Every tournament (transitive or otherwise) has a Hamilton path, that is, a directed path that contains every vertex of the tournament. The start-vertex of this path is the sought-after vertex of out-degree $n-1$.

Comment: @Kris Letang: For a proof that every tournament has a Hamilton path check out http://www.math.toronto.edu/gscott/sept20_2016.pdf Alternatively you can deduce this claim from a theorem by Gallai and Milgram which can be found as theorem 2.5.1 on page 52 of Diestel's "Graph Theory", 5th edition.